# Routing for self-referencing association in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, self-reference, nested-routes

I am attempting to set up a route for a self-referencing nested association.  The goal is to get a URL of `/category_name/subcategory_name`.

I'm using friendly_urls to get the category names instead of IDs.  I've been able to get half of it to work with this:

`match '/:id' => 'listing#index', :via => 'get', as: 'category'`

However, everything I try to get the subcategory to work is failing?  The only answers I've come across are to create another model/controller for the subcategories.  If possible, I'd like to avoid that as it'll add extra complexity for little gain.  I wouldn't really need any of the extra methods/flexibility that separate methods might provide.

This is my first Rails app so please excuse the basic nature of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I make this way:

Define routes:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :categories, path: '/'
end
```

Which `rake routes` show:

```
   category_categories GET    /categories/:category_id(.:format)          categories#index
                       POST   /categories/:category_id(.:format)          categories#create
 new_category_category GET    /categories/:category_id/new(.:format)      categories#new
edit_category_category GET    /categories/:category_id/:id/edit(.:format) categories#edit
     category_category GET    /categories/:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#show
                       PATCH  /categories/:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#update
                       PUT    /categories/:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#update
                       DELETE /categories/:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#destroy
            categories GET    /categories(.:format)                       categories#index
                       POST   /categories(.:format)                       categories#create
          new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                   categories#new
         edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)              categories#edit
              category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                   categories#show
                       PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                   categories#update
                       PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                   categories#update
                       DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                   categories#destroy
```

On the `categories_controller` you can identify a nested category (subcategory) because `params[:category_id]` is not `nil`. And if it is `nil` the action is for a parent category.

**Edit**
Added `path` option.

I think you want this:

```
   category_categories GET    /:category_id(.:format)          categories#index
                       POST   /:category_id(.:format)          categories#create
 new_category_category GET    /:category_id/new(.:format)      categories#new
edit_category_category GET    /:category_id/:id/edit(.:format) categories#edit
     category_category GET    /:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#show
                       PATCH  /:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#update
                       PUT    /:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#update
                       DELETE /:category_id/:id(.:format)      categories#destroy
            categories GET    /                                categories#index
                       POST   /                                categories#create
          new_category GET    /new(.:format)                   categories#new
         edit_category GET    /:id/edit(.:format)              categories#edit
              category GET    /:id(.:format)                   categories#show
                       PATCH  /:id(.:format)                   categories#update
                       PUT    /:id(.:format)                   categories#update
                       DELETE /:id(.:format)                   categories#destroy
```

you must do the same on the outer route:

```
resources :categories, path: '/' do
  resources :categories, path: '/'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your routes file or definitively knowing the name of your controller (`listing` should probably be `listings` since Rails controllers are typically plural, unless of course you consciously named your controller `listing`).

Assuming the controller is listings and you want to pass in category names and subcategory names to that controllers index method, I would make my `match|get` route the following:

```
get '/:category_name/:subcategory_name', to: 'listings#index', as: 'category'
```

Then, in the index method of the ListingsController, I could potentially (assuming they're provided) check for `params[:category_name]` and `params[:subcategory_name]` and act on them accordingly.

The [Rails Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is pretty helpful, too.